# Global variable does not have global scope

Tags: autohotkey

```
supposedlyGlobalVariable := "blah"

ARoutine()
{
   localVariable := "asdf"
   MsgBox, The global variable value is %supposedlyGlobalVariable%.  The local variable value is %localVariable%.
}


^!X:: ;This assigns the hotkey CTRL + ALT + X to run the routine
ARoutine()
return
```

Run the code and the result is:

```
"The global variable value is .  The local variable value is asdf."
```

The [documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm) states:

> **Variable scope and declarations:** With the exception of local variables
>   in functions, all variables are global; that is, their contents may be
>   read or altered by *any* part of the script.

Why does my global variable not have scope within the function?

Comment: Did you designate "`supposedlyGlobalVariable`" as Global at the top? If you add the line "`Global supposedlyGlobalVariable`" prior to declaring its value, it will work.  EDIT: Oh, I see, it looks like you didn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation for global variables can be found here:
https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Global

> **Global variables**
>
> To refer to an existing global variable inside a function (or create a
>   new one), declare the variable as global prior to using it. For
>   example:

```
LogToFile(TextToLog)
{
    global LogFileName
    FileAppend, %TextToLog%`n, %LogFileName%
}
```

I believe the concept of global, with AHK, is a bit different than in other languages. With AHK you can create a variable and use it within multiple hotkeys, and subroutines, without declaring it as global.

```
Gv := 0

f1::SetTimer, Action, % (on:=!on) ? (1000) : ("Off")

Action:
    Gv++
    trayTip,, % Gv
Return

f2::Msgbox, % Gv
```

Explaination of code:

- The <kbd>F1</kbd> key toggles a timer to run the subroutine: `Action` every `1000`ms.
- `%` starts an expression.
- `on:=!on` reverses the binary value of variable `on` every time <kbd>F1</kbd> is pressed.
- `?:` together is called the ternary operator.
- When on=1 delay is set to `1000`ms; when on=0 the timer is turned `Off`.

The `++`  operator adds 1 to variable Gv.

Comment: That is counter-intuitive.  If a variable is global, but not inside a function...then where is it global without requiring a modifier?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I've updated my answer in an attempt to address your comment.

Comment: Don't know why this answers OP question? Putting the Global inside a function is not usually needed, and not what OP wants.

Answer (score 10):

This makes things easier:

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#SuperGlobal

> **Super-global variables [v1.1.05+]**: If a global declaration appears
>   outside of any function, it takes effect for all functions by default
>   (excluding force-local functions). This avoids the need to redeclare
>   the variable in each function. However, if a function parameter or
>   local variable with the same name is declared, it takes precedence
>   over the global variable. Variables created by the class keyword are
>   also super-global.

Just declare your variable as global in the main script:

```
global supposedlyGlobalVariable := "blah"
```

Comment: YES!  This is all OP needs to do: modify as shown.  Or as I suggest in my comment, just add the `Global supposedlyGlobalVariable` at top before declaring its value.

Comment: This doesn't work: `global test := "1"`   `f11:: msgbox test` Am I missing something?

Comment: you need `f11::msgbox, % test` or `f11::msgbox, %test%`

Answer (score -1):

P.Brian, It works when you do this.. I know it doesn't explain why, but this might be your workaround.

```
#Persistent
GlobalVariable = "blah"
RETURN

ARoutine:
{
   localVariable := "asdf"
   MsgBox, The global variable value is %GlobalVariable%.  The local variable value is %localVariable%.
}
Return

^!X:: ;This assigns the hotkey CTRL + ALT + X to run the routine
gosub, ARoutine
return
```

Comment: Sure, this works - but isn't an answer. Why change to using subroutine here? OP wants to use the variable in a function.  And you don't even need to make it Global for using it in subroutines, in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to declare the variable as global inside your function

```
supposedlyGlobalVariable := "blah"

ARoutine()
{
   global supposedlyGlobalVariable
   localVariable := "asdf"
   MsgBox, The global variable value is %supposedlyGlobalVariable%.  The local variable 
value is %localVariable%.
}


^!X:: ;This assigns the hotkey CTRL + ALT + X to run the routine
ARoutine()
return
```

Comment: Totally defeats the purpose. OP wants the declaration OUTSIDE the function.  You CAN declare it inside a function, but then you have to use the function at least once before you need that variable anywhere else.

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm getting an error "This variable has not been assigned a value" and the global variable is empty.